# Фильтрация по характеристикам товара

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с характеристиками товаров и столбцами `Good_ID`, `Field_ID`, `Value`. Может быть сколько угодно записей с одним `Good_ID` и разными `Field_ID` и `Value`.

`Field_ID` - это идентификатор определенной характеристики

Нужно написать запрос, чтобы выбирались `Good_ID`, которые удовлетворяют нескольким парам `Field_ID` и `Value`. По сути фильтрация по характеристикам товара.

Не могу придумать, как одним запросом выбрать из таблицы все товары, у которых цвет синий и вес до 1кг.

**Обновление**

Всем спасибо. В общем в итоге получилось реализовать вот так

```
SELECT DISTINCT Good_ID FROM chars WHERE 
Message_ID IN (SELECT Good_ID FROM chars WHERE  Field_ID = 3 AND Value = 'серый')
AND   Message_ID IN (SELECT Good_ID FROM chars WHERE  Field_ID = 2 AND Value = '3')
```

Если я не правильно составил запрос - поправьте плз.

Comment: @titov_andrei не стоит использоать [tag:запрос], метка не добавляет смысла к вопросу. [Запрос на удаление](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2208)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У Вас должна быть таблица со списком товаров. Типа `goods`. Т.е. `Good_ID` это `id` из этой таблицы.
Далее, предположим, что:

- Ваша таблица с характеристиками называется `attributes`.
- `Field_ID` для цвета = 1
- `Field_ID` для веса = 2

Тогда нужный Вам запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT g.* FROM goods g
JOIN attributes aCo AS g.id=aCO.Good_ID AND aCo.Field_ID=1 AND aCo.value='синий'
JOIN attributes aW AS g.id=aW.Good_ID AND aW.Field_ID=2 AND aW.value=1
```

Этот запрос покажет Вам все товары из таблицы `goods`, у которых цвет (`Field_ID=1`) синий, а вес (`Field_ID=2`) = 1.

---

У меня на сайтах реализована описанная Вами схема, поэтому позволю себе дать Вам совет: будет лучше, если Вы сделаете сводную таблицу всех товаров и их аттрибутов. Можно туда добавить другую информацию: цены, описания, названия, картинки...

Что-то типа такого:

```
Good_ID  SKU         title                    price   a1    a2  a3  
-------  ---------   ---------------------    ------  ---   --- ---
      2  [артикул]   [наименование товара]    450.00  red   3   45
    452  [артикул2]  [наименование товара 2]   15.00  white 5   64
```

`a1`, `a2`, `a3` -  это значения аттрибутов 1, 2 и 3 (у Вас `Field_ID`).
В зависимости от того, как часто меняется информация о товаре можно такую таблицу генерировать заново раз в час / несколько часов / раз в сутки.

Имея такую таблицу, Вам будет намного проще доставать данные из базы, делать отчеты, можно сделать быстрый (очень быстрый) поиск на сайте (ведь запросы любой сложности будут всегда в одну таблицу)... ну еще много всего....

Очень советую.

Comment: тоже была необходимость фильтровать подобным образом, `join` работал как то медленно, сделал при помощи `union`, т.е. `select необходимые поля from table where условие union следующее условие` и последующей группировки. за создания таблицы отдельное спасибо

Comment: К сожалению не возможности изменять таблицу, так как проект боевой и стоит задача только доставать информацию из существующей таблицы. Интересно, когда будет сразу фильтроваться по 20-ти характеристикам не будет join подтормаживать?

Comment: много join скорее всего будут тормозить. возможно join с `(select 1,'синий' from DUAL union select 2,'1'  from DUAL)` и посчитать количество совпадений по каждой id (в общем похоже на идею из второго ответа) будет быстрее, а может и нет. В зависимости от данных. И автор данного ответа предложил не менять структуру существующей таблицы, а сделать кеш-таблицу, которую формировать время от времени. надо только посмотреть сколько времени она формироваться будет

Comment: @Bald56rus запрос с UNION мне почему-то отдает Good_ID так если бы в обычном запросе просто поставить OR
т.е. и синий цвет и вес 1кг в результатах, но так же и черный цвет и вес 1 кг например

Comment: Чем больше `join`, тем больше будет притормаживать. А если Вам понадобиться делать `LEFT JOIN`, то будет еще хуже. Как быстрее, с `UNION` или без Вам придется проверять самому - зависит от фильтрационных данных, размера таблицы.

Comment: @Mike у меня кое-где такая таблица генерируется аж 5 минут. Аттрибутов много, плюс много других параметров я вношу в таблицу. У меня две кэш-таблицы. Одна "рабочая", вторая "живая". Они идентичны. Сайт всегда пользуется лишь "живой" таблицей. А вся основная работа по генерации происходит в "рабочей". Когда процесс закончен, одним запросом `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` я переношу данные из "рабочей" в "живую". Имея такую структуру мне не очень важно, сколько времени занимает регенерация - посетители этого не замечают...

Comment: @cyadvert Я бы при долгой генерации, в триггерах на таблицу с основными данными писал бы в отдельную таблицу id записей по которым были изменения и перегенерил бы кеш только для них.

Comment: @Mike, да, хороший вариант. Только я делал не на триггере, а с использованием поля `dateUpdated TIMESTAMP`, сравнивая ее с датой последней регенерации. Впрочем, тут несколько вариантов... :) Лишь бы работало :)

Answer (score 1):

Что-то похожее на это, можно попробовать:

```
SELECT Good_ID FROM table 
WHERE (Field_ID in(идентификатор цвета, идентификатор веса) 
AND (Value=параметр отвечающий за синий or Value<=1)) 
GROUP BY Good_ID 
HAVING Count(*)=2
```